# Docker Ubuntu image can't find /bin/sh

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to run a script in a docker image and I keep getting the following error

```
Step 4/4 : RUN ./config.sh /config.sh
 ---> Running in a0739624bcb7
failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

My docker file is based upon Ubuntu, so I'm unsure why this error even occurs, I found a lot of these issues because people use scratch

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV ACCESS_TOKEN ""

COPY ./config.sh /config.sh

RUN /config.sh $ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I tried so many things, and it just doesn't make sense, I tried `docker rmi ubuntu` and `docker system prune` in case this would be a corruption of the image, but to no avail.

With that being said, I'm still able to do the following, so any insight is welcome

```bash
docker run -it ubuntu:20.04 /bin/sh
docker run -it ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash
```

Also, my script has a shebang for `/bin/bash`, so why is the issue with `/bin/sh`

Comment: `RUN ./config.sh` `RUN /config.sh` The output doesn't match the Dockerfile. What kernel version are you running? On what host are you running? `I'm still able to do the following` Are you able to do `stat /bin/sh` _inside_ the docker container after doing the following?

Comment: add ```#!/bin/bash``` to start of your script

Comment: Is it possible your script has DOS line endings?  Usually there's some visual glitches associated with that, but that could cause a "bad interpreter" error from trying to run `/bin/sh^M`.

Comment: Hi, I'm running Regolith linux ```Linux version 5.4.0-122-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-095) (gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1))``` and as mentioned in the question, my script has a shebang, the script works locally, but not on the container, doesn't seem to be an interpreter problem but it could be

Answer (score -4):

I'm now running into the same problem when using FROM ubuntu:20.04.

Using FROM ubuntu:18.04 or FROM phusion/baseimage:18.04-1.0.0-amd64 both work OK with my dockerfile.

Output when creating the docker image:

Sending build context to Docker daemon  301.5MB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
20.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
eaead16dc43b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:450e066588f42ebe1551f3b1a535034b6aa46cd936fe7f2c6b0d72997ec61dbd
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:20.04
---> 680e5dfb52c7
Step 2/3 : COPY . /
---> 8623e2ab9bb0
Step 3/3 : RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libprotobuf17 libjson-c4 libpcap0.8 iproute2 ethtool pciutils inotify-tools python3-pip libnuma1 gdb libgoogle-perftools-dev rsyslog && pip3 install requests && ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && echo apt-get DONE
---> Running in 3e0fffb2b1fd
failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown

From docker info:
Server Version: 20.10.17
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-131-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu Core 18

Running on a VM with:
Linux ubuntu-dev3 5.4.0-131-generic #147-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 14 17:07:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ixia@ubuntu-dev3:~/git/GSC/next_gen_gsc/GscApp$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

As [MathieuAuclair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7253534/mathieuauclair) stated, I can also just run the ubuntu:20.04 image by itself and it it is OK.
I can execute /bin/sh and /bin/bash from inside the container.

Comment: Are you also having the issue, or are you trying to give an answer?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33098149)